# Reading Cifar10 dataset in batches

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision, batch-processing

i am trying to read the CIFAR10 datasets, given in batches from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html>. i am trying to put it in a data frame using pickle and read 'data' part of it. But i am getting this error .

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-8758b7a31925> in <module>()
----> 1 unpickle('datasets/cifar-10-batches-py/test_batch')

<ipython-input-23-04002b89d842> in unpickle(file)
      3     fo = open(file, 'rb')
      4     dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding ='bytes')
----> 5     X = dict['data']
      6     fo.close()
      7     return dict
```

KeyError: 'data'.

i am using ipython and here is my code :

```
def unpickle(file):

 fo = open(file, 'rb')
 dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding ='bytes')
 X = dict['data']
 fo.close()
 return dict

unpickle('datasets/cifar-10-batches-py/test_batch')
```

Comment: add print dict.keys() and see what is inside

Comment: @lejlot dict_keys([b'batch_label', b'data', b'labels', b'filenames']) ..

Comment: try to do `X = dict[b'data']` then

Comment: yeah ..just done that turns out its working :) ...anyways thanks @lejlot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can read cifar 10 datasets by the code given below only make sure that you are giving write directory where the batches are placed

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from six.moves import cPickle as pickle
import os
import platform
from subprocess import check_output
classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')

%matplotlib inline


img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 3)
def load_pickle(f):
    version = platform.python_version_tuple()
    if version[0] == '2':
        return  pickle.load(f)
    elif version[0] == '3':
        return  pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
    raise ValueError("invalid python version: {}".format(version))

def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):
    """ load single batch of cifar """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        datadict = load_pickle(f)
        X = datadict['data']
        Y = datadict['labels']
        X = X.reshape(10000,3072)
        Y = np.array(Y)
        return X, Y

def load_CIFAR10(ROOT):
    """ load all of cifar """
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for b in range(1,6):
        f = os.path.join(ROOT, 'data_batch_%d' % (b, ))
        X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f)
        xs.append(X)
        ys.append(Y)
    Xtr = np.concatenate(xs)
    Ytr = np.concatenate(ys)
    del X, Y
    Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR_batch(os.path.join(ROOT, 'test_batch'))
    return Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte
def get_CIFAR10_data(num_training=49000, num_validation=1000, num_test=10000):
    # Load the raw CIFAR-10 data
    cifar10_dir = '../input/cifar-10-batches-py/'
    X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_CIFAR10(cifar10_dir)

    # Subsample the data
    mask = range(num_training, num_training + num_validation)
    X_val = X_train[mask]
    y_val = y_train[mask]
    mask = range(num_training)
    X_train = X_train[mask]
    y_train = y_train[mask]
    mask = range(num_test)
    X_test = X_test[mask]
    y_test = y_test[mask]

    x_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = X_test.astype('float32')

    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255

    return x_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, x_test, y_test


# Invoke the above function to get our data.
x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val, x_test, y_test = get_CIFAR10_data()


print('Train data shape: ', x_train.shape)
print('Train labels shape: ', y_train.shape)
print('Validation data shape: ', x_val.shape)
print('Validation labels shape: ', y_val.shape)
print('Test data shape: ', x_test.shape)
print('Test labels shape: ', y_test.shape)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the reason! I had the same problem and I solved it !
The key problem is about the encoding method, change the code from

```
dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding ='bytes')
```

to

```
dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding ='latin1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through similar issues in the past.

I'd like to mention for future readers that you can find [here](https://github.com/ndrplz/CIFAR-10) a python wrapper for automatically downloading, extracting and parsing the cifar10 dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on [Sohaib Anwaar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51694265/5070460) above, but with changes to obtain dataset as TensorFlow `Dataset` ([tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)) instead of NumPy array.

#### Why TensorFlow `Dataset`?

`tf.data.Datasets` offers easy-to-use and high-performance input pipelines and is the ["correct"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67636211/5070460) way to access any dataset in TensorFlow 2.x.

#### Python version >= 3.10

For python version >= 3.10 the solution to obtain TensorFlow `Dataset` is very simple using [`tensorflow_datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets).

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


(ds_train, ds_cval, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    "cifar10",
    split=["train[:75%]", "train[75%:]", "test"], 
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True
)

print("Train dataset size:", len(ds_train))
print("Cross-validation dataset size:", len(ds_cval))
print("Test dataset size:", len(ds_test))
```

##### Output

```
Train dataset size: 37500
Cross-validation dataset size: 12500
Test dataset size: 10000
```

#### Python version <= 3.9.x

After downloading [CIFAR-10](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz) dataset, extract the `tar.gz` contents to a folder named `data`.

##### Changes from accepted answer

1. `load_CIFAR10` returns TensorFlow `Dataset` instead of NumPy array.
2. `load_CIFAR10` splits dataset into Train, Cross-Validation and Test sets.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

import os
import math
import platform
import pickle
```

```py
def load_CIFAR_batch(file_path):
    """
    Load single batch of CIFAR-10 images from
    the binary file and return as a NumPy array.
    """
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        data_dict = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")

        # Extract NumPy from dictionary.
        X = data_dict["data"]
        y = data_dict["labels"]

        # Reshape and transpose flat array as 32 X 32 RGB image.
        X = X.reshape(CIFAR_BATCH_SIZE, *input_shape, order="F")
        X = X.transpose((0, 2, 1, 3))

        # Convert `labels` to vector.
        y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)

        return X, y
```

```py
def load_CIFAR10(cv_size=0.25):
    """
    Load all batches of CIFAR-10 images from the
    binary file and return as TensorFlow DataSet.
    """
    X_btchs = []
    y_btchs = []
    for batch in range(1, 6):
        file_path = os.path.join(ROOT, "data_batch_%d" % (batch,))
        X, y = load_CIFAR_batch(file_path)
        X_btchs.append(X)
        y_btchs.append(y)

    # Combine all batches.
    all_Xbs = np.concatenate(X_btchs)
    all_ybs = np.concatenate(y_btchs)

    # Convert Train dataset from NumPy array to TensorFlow Dataset.
    ds_all = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((all_Xbs, all_ybs))

    al_size = len(ds_all)
    tr_size = math.ceil((1 - cv_size) * al_size)
    # Split dataset into Train and Cross-validation sets.
    ds_tr = ds_all.take(tr_size)
    ds_cv = ds_all.skip(tr_size)
    print(f"Train dataset size: {tr_size}.")
    print(f"Cross-validation dataset size: {al_size - tr_size}.")

    # Convert Test dataset from NumPy array to TensorFlow Dataset.
    X_ts, y_ts = load_CIFAR_batch(os.path.join(ROOT, "test_batch"))
    ds_ts = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_ts, y_ts))
    print(f"Test dataset size {len(ds_ts)}.")

    return ds_tr, ds_cv, ds_ts
```

```py
ROOT = "../data/cifar-10-batches-py/"

CIFAR_BATCH_SIZE = 10000
img_rows, img_cols = 32, 32
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 3)

ds_tr, ds_cv, ds_ts = load_CIFAR10()
```

##### Output

```
Train dataset size: 37500.
Cross-validation dataset size: 12500.
Test dataset size 10000.
```

##### Confirm Dataset

```py
xi, yi = ds_tr.as_numpy_iterator().next()

plt.imshow(xi)
plt.title(f"Class label: {yi[0]}")
plt.show()
```

[image: Frog image]

P.S.
Above image is very low quality 32X32 dimension image of a frog.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`def unpickle(file):
    import cPickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        data = cPickle.load(fo)
    return data`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.