# Using Cifar-10 dataset from tfds.load() correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use the Cifar-10 dataset to practice my CNN skills.

If I do this it's ok:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

But I was trying to use `tfds.load()` and I don't understand how to do it.

With this I download it,

```
train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('cifar10', split=['train','test'])
```

Now I tried this but is not working,

```
assert isinstance(train_ds, tf.data.Dataset)
assert isinstance(test_ds, tf.data.Dataset)
(train_images, train_labels) = tuple(zip(*train_ds))
(test_images, test_labels) = tuple(zip(*test_ds))
```

Can somebody show me the way to achieve it?

thank you!

Comment: What do you wan to to do? You can pass a tf.data.Dataset object directly to `model.fit` if your plan is to use it with a keras model.

Comment: Extract it to do some processing as normalization, data augmentation...

Comment: You don't need to extract it, you can map an augmentation to a tf.data.Dataset

Comment: I suggest you to read this guide: [tf.data: Build TensorFlow input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) and then come back to make your question more focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also extract them like this:

```
train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('cifar10', split=['train','test'], 
                               as_supervised = True, 
                               batch_size = -1)
```

To work with `as_numpy()` method, you need pass `as_supervised` and `batch_size` as shown. If you pass `as_supervised = True` then the dataset will have tuple structure that (inputs, labels) otherwise it will be a dictionary.

With them you simply call:

```
train_images, train_labels = tfds.as_numpy(train_ds)
```

Or another way is to iterate over it to obtain classes(assuming `batch_size` is not passed).

With `as_supervised = False`:

```
train_images, train_labels = [],[]

for images_labels in train_ds:
    train_images.append(images_labels['image'])
    train_labels.append(images_labels['label'])
```

With `as_supervised = True`:

```
for images, labels in train_ds:
    train_images.append(images)
    train_labels.append(labels)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this as follows.

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('cifar10', split=['train','test'], as_supervised=True)
```

These `train_ds` and `test_ds` are `tf.data.Dataset` objects and so you can use `map`, `batch`, and similar functions to each of those.

```
def normalize_resize(image, label):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.divide(image, 255)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (28, 28))
    return image, label

def augment(image, label):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 0.7, 1.3)
    image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, 0.8, 1.2)
    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, 0.1)
    return image, label 

train = train_ds.map(normalize_resize).cache().map(augment).shuffle(100).batch(64).repeat()
test = test_ds.map(normalize_resize).cache().batch(64)
```

Now, we can pass `train` and `test` directly to `model.fit`.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 3)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
        ]
    )

model.compile(
    optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
)
model.fit(
    train,
    epochs=5,
    steps_per_epoch=60000 // 64,
    validation_data=test, verbose=2
)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
17s 17ms/step - loss: 2.0848 - accuracy: 0.2318 - val_loss: 1.8175 - val_accuracy: 0.3411
Epoch 2/5
11s 12ms/step - loss: 1.8827 - accuracy: 0.3144 - val_loss: 1.7800 - val_accuracy: 0.3595
Epoch 3/5
11s 12ms/step - loss: 1.8383 - accuracy: 0.3272 - val_loss: 1.7152 - val_accuracy: 0.3904
Epoch 4/5
11s 11ms/step - loss: 1.8129 - accuracy: 0.3397 - val_loss: 1.6908 - val_accuracy: 0.4060
Epoch 5/5
11s 11ms/step - loss: 1.8022 - accuracy: 0.3461 - val_loss: 1.6801 - val_accuracy: 0.4081
```

Comment: you are missing the number of validation steps. Without it, it gives the error `ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model, you should specify the 'steps_per_epoch' argument.`

Comment: In my answer above, I did use `step_per_epoch` for the training set (as I used `.repeat()`) but I think I don't have to explicitly declare `validation_step` (as I didn't use `.repeat()` on validation data.

Comment: Maybe I missed something. I had an error that went away when specifying the `validation steps` number. Anyway, good answer!